# The distance the Earth travels in one day

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the distance that the Earth travels in one day in its path around the Sun. Assume that a year has 365 days and that the path of the Earth around the Sun is a circle of radius 93 million miles.

I'm doing precalc review for a calc class and I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, if it takes 365 days to travel $2\pi\times 93\text{ million miles}$, then it takes 1 day to travel ______. Fill in the blank. (Hint: ratios)

Comment: x/1 = (2pi * 93,000,000) / 365?? so x=1600921.188?

Comment: Good work. :) $\text{}$

Comment: ratios are awesome! thanks :)

Comment: @J.M. You should post the hint as an answer. :)

Comment: @Sri: Dunno, I'm thinking it might be a good idea for KubaSub to try to write his solution in his own words. (For instance, where did I get the $2\pi\times 93$ million miles? KubaSub should answer that himself, if he truly understood what I did there.) ;)

Comment: Well somebody should post *something* as an answer!

Comment: @The Chaz: Done.

Comment: Very late, but since this has gotten bumped: There's no justification for carrying the answer to greater accuracy than $1\,600\,000$ miles, since the _earth's radius_ is a few times larger than $921$ miles. Carrying the answer to three decimals (an asserted accuracy of a few feet) is comical.

Answer (score 5):

The circumference of a circle of radius $r$ is $2\pi r$; you’ve been given $r$, so you can find the circumference of the orbit. It takes the Earth $365$ days to travel that distance, so in $1$ day it travels what fraction of the circumference?